# Why do we have to estimate the autocorrelation coefficient when using GLS?

Tags: regression, least-squares, autocorrelation, generalized-least-squares

Suppose we have a linear regression model with autocorrelated error terms and we know it is AR(1) by for example investigating both the ACF and the PACF plot (I know there are probably more sophisticated methods, but I am an undergrad student with basically no or minimal experience in this field).

I do not understand why we have to estimate ***ρ*** (the autocorrelation coefficient) in order to use the Generalized Least Squares method?

I am currently reading Time Series Analysis by Box and Jenkins and to me it seems pretty straight forward to compute ***ρ*** for a given parameter. The concept is easily applicable on the residuals we get when computing the regression via OLS. So why do we need to estimate ***ρ*** by using methods such as Cochrane-Orcutt in order to make GLS *feasible*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you did not estimate $\rho$, what value would you use when actually implementing the GLS (*some* particular value is needed)? How would you choose it if not from the data via estimation?

Comment: I would assume that ρ is known in every case due to the known formula $$
\rho = \frac{\hbox{E}\left[(y_1-\mu_1)(y_2-\mu_2)\right]}{\sigma_1 \sigma_2} =
\frac{\hbox{Cov}(y_1, y_2)}{\sigma_1 \sigma_2} 
$$
 So why is there a need for other methods?

Comment: In the real world, you hardly ever know the true expected values, the true covariance, or the true standard deviations. Rather, you typically estimate them from the data. That is why you use an estimated $\hat\rho$ in place of the true $\rho$.

Comment: So the above mentioned formula is basically not applicable, because we do not know the actual parameters (we can just estimate them), correct? So why do we use it in the first place - why is it common practice to plot the ACF and PACF by using the above mentioned formula in order to determine certain characteristics of a regression model, for example if it is autoregressive and if so, which AR(k) is present.

Comment: Correct. And the ACF and PACF you typically see are empirical, i.e. estimated form the data.

Comment: I misspelled so I deleted my comment: What do you mean by estimated from the data? To my understanding the plots underlying formula is the above one. This essentially means that it is okay to use the formula when acf/pacf plotting the error terms of a regression modell in order to make assumptions about the order of the autoregressive term etc., but it is not okay to use the **same results** to estimate the GLE parameters... I do not get that.

Comment: @RichardHardy A more concrete example would be: If I computed the autocorrelation at lag 1 for the residuals of a regression model with the above mentioned formula - what prohibits me from using that exact result when implementing GLS for an AR(1) model?

Comment: You cannot use the above formula because you do not know $\mu_1, \mu_2, \sigma_1, \sigma_2$ nor do you know $\mathbb{E(\cdot)}$ or $\text{Cov}(\cdot)$ -- all these are theoretical quantities that are not available to you in practice.

Comment: Yet, I can use that formula when computing the autocorrelation coefficient in the context acf plots. Is the difference that acf plots are simply describing the data, whereas estimating the **real** autocorrelation coefficient is a whole different thing and thus a different approach is required?

Comment: No, you cannot use it, unless God gave you the values $\mu_1$ etc. Otherwise, where do you take them from?

Comment: If I estimate the regression model by implementing OLS I get residuals. I can then use those residuals by plotting the respective acf funtction for the residuals.

Comment: And how do you do that? I can tell you, not by using the formula involving theoretical quantities. You use empirical counterparts.

Comment: Yes empirical counterparts, you are right. So it comes down to the difference between true or theoretical quantities and empirical quantities. And you can not use the latter when trying to implement GLS, whereas you can use them when trying to detect autocorrelation in the given function by plotting etc. I hope that´s it now (correct me if not)... Sorry for bothering and thank you for staying with me on this.

Comment: You almost never use the theoretical quantities because you do not know them, and you cannot use them without knowing them. Specifically, you cannot use them when trying to detect autocorrelation, which is in contrast to your last comment. You cannot use them in feasible GLS either.